# Youtube-api :: setting metadata fields via command-line

Tags: python, youtube-api, argparse

Sorry for the basic question, but I've been looking everywhere for an example of usage of an `youtube api` call via `command-line`, and how to set its proper metadata fields.

The code below is provided by Google here: [Search Youtube by 'keyword'](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#search_by_keyword)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser

DEVELOPER_KEY = "mykey"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  videos = []
  channels = []
  playlists = []

  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                 search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
      channels.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                   search_result["id"]["channelId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#playlist":
      playlists.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                    search_result["id"]["playlistId"]))

  print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"
  print "Channels:\n", "\n".join(channels), "\n"
  print "Playlists:\n", "\n".join(playlists), "\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default="Google")
  argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
  args = argparser.parse_args()

  try:
    youtube_search(args)
  except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
search.py
```

I've followed the example given here: [Youtube>Data API>SampleRequests](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video#Sample_Requests)

searching, for example, for the *Karma Police video*, I have tried, accordingly:

`$ python script.py --q="karma police"`, to no avail. It prints nothing.

What am I missing?

**ps.** further credentials are set in an enviroment `.json file` located on the same directory.

EDIT: traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audio.py", line 64, in <module>
    youtube_search(args)
  File "audio.py", line 24, in youtube_search
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 226, in build
    credentials=credentials)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 358, in build_from_document
    credentials = _auth.default_credentials()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_auth.py", line 41, in default_credentials
    return oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1264, in get_application_default
    return GoogleCredentials._get_implicit_credentials()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1249, in _get_implicit_credentials
    credentials = checker()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1200, in _implicit_credentials_from_files
    credentials_filename = _get_environment_variable_file()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1348, in _get_environment_variable_file
    ' environment variable) does not exist!')
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: File “/Users//api/youtube/urlaudio/myproject.json” (pointed by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) does not exist!
```

Comment: it prints nothing? So it does not reach this line: `print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"`

Comment: did you check how far the execution reaches? e.g. I usually just add some `print('1')` code between the lines to check where the execution stops

Comment: it works on my machine :-) see [output of your script on my computer](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/cfbdaa202e121fb2b46a566479577d56)

Comment: what does `python --version`? say?

Comment: it says here: `(pointed by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) does not exist!
`

Comment: I thought it prints nothing? Can you add the error message into your question?

Comment: no it prints that error now. I will edit the quesiton with traceback.

Comment: does `/Users//api/youtube/urlaudio/myproject.json` exist? if yes, is that the credential file you downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow through the steps [provided in the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials). In the end you need to point `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the json file you downloaded, e.g.:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/Downloads/youtube-search-b0e0b347241c.json
```

Of course you best move that file somewhere safe, e.g. into `~/.credentials/` and `chmod 700` that directory.